# add an event after people click confirmation link email

Tags: newsletter, newsletter-subscriber, confirmation

I want to add an event when people click the confirmation email link to confirm the as a newsletter subscriber.

where I should add this event inside the magento?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific event for that.

Byt you can use model event for that.

You can use model_save_after or model_save_before and then you can check and add your logic for your click.

You can see all event list in below link.

Please refer this link:- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Hope this will work for you.

Thank you